# Z index Refuses To Work Properly - Tried Everything. Frustrated

Tags: gallery, z-index

I'm currently trying to program a 'Customize Your Home' image gallery that would allow users to click & choose different colors for different elements.

The fiddle can be seen right here: https://jsfiddle.net/lft11501/ug7ke69n/4/

HTML:

```css
/* here's z-index in action */

#warning
{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:0;
}

#message
{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
}

#more
{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
}

#side
{
  position:relative;
  z-index:3;
}

/* this is to make the demo look pretty */

#warning
{
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  background:#fcc;
  border:0px solid red;
  width:400px;
  height:256px;
}

#message
{
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  border:0px solid blue;
  width:400px;
  height:256px;
}

#more
{
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  border:0px solid blue;
  width:400px;
  height:256px;
}

#side
{
  left:400px;
  top:0px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  width:400px;
  height:256px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="warning"><img src="http://gomocloud.com/misc/images/z-index-test-bg.jpg"></div>

<div id="message"><img src="http://gomocloud.com/misc/images/roof.png"></div>

<div id="more"><img src="http://gomocloud.com/misc/images/siding.png"></div>
<div id="side"><a href="http://gomocloud.com/misc/images/roof2.png" target="#message">Test</div>
```

I already know that different elements need different z-indexes in order to stack more than one element in the same space.  I only included one link as a test.  However instead of the image appearing within the box, it opens to a new window.

I don't understand why this isn't working properly.  I have followed every step to the letter and gone through every code and element with a fine-tooth comb.  This is frustrating!  I'm about to give up.

Comment: Start by closing your anchor tag `...Test</a>`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `target="#message"` in your anchor element?

Comment: That's where I want the image to appear when the link is clicked.

Comment: I updated the closing anchor tag.  Same problem.  Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lft11501/ug7ke69n/5/

Comment: I don't think the `target` attribute works that way. Check the spec and MDN for possible guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The `target` attribute on the `<a>` tag is the name you are giving to the window or tab where the link will open. The `<a>` tag is generally all about changing where on the web a user is located.
When you click "Test" you are opening a new tab with the internal name "#message". Here is a [reference for the `target` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target).

In order to do what you want (changing the image when the user clicks on part of the house), you will need to write some JavaScript.